# Sass escaping quotation marks - Font Awesome 5

Tags: sass, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to integrate font awesome 5 into my project, using Sass.
The icons haven't been showing, but the files all load correctly, I eventually worked out that it's because it doesn't seem to escape the quotes correct.

This line

```
 @return unquote("\"#{ $fa-var }\"")
```

Should for example output

```
"\f00c"
```

But is instead outputting

```
\"\f00c\"
```

I've searched and this seems to be the correct way to escape quotes so I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Why quoting unquoting the variable like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to update your sass compiler to the latest version**, define your document encoding:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

and then just return the plain FOnt Awesome variable:

```
@return $fa-var;
```

> Sass now follows the CSS Syntax Level 3 specification for determining a stylesheet’s encoding. In addition, it now only emits UTF-8 CSS rather than trying to match the source encoding.

Comment: I did as you suggested and still not showing the icons. Are you suggesting this is a bug in Font Awesome 5 as your answer suggesting changing their code?

Comment: @milky_jay I don’t get it then. The return is from a font awesome function or from a custom function? It was a sass bug. I tested it importing the mixins into my main sass file and it works this way. Can you provide the exact full implementation you are using?

Comment: I've just included the font awesome files into my sass project and called the icons using the relevant classes. I'll try a different compiler in case that's the issue

Comment: @milky_jay unicode is a compiler issue. I use the latest version of node-sass. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I use a sass plugin in coda 2. I just tried it with node-sass, and it worked as expected, so that plugin must be the issue. Thanks

Comment: @milky_jay that’s why my answer started as: “you need to update your sass compiler to the latest version...” if it solved your issue mark it as solved would you? :-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, best solution is to update SASS compiler, but for those unable to do it (using VS2013 and web essentials), there is a workoaround:

```
@return unquote('"#{ $fa-var }"');
```